# Using socket.io without an HTML file

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to exchange data between two javascript files with socket.io without using a HTML file for embedding my client side js. I want something like this -

server.js -

```
const express = require('express`);
const app = express();
server = app.listen(3000);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection',(socket) => {
    console.log('Connected user');
    socket.on('new-user',(name) => {
       console.log(name);
    });
});
```

Client.js

```
var io = require('socket.io-client'),
socket = io.connect('localhost', {
    port: 3000
});

let name="Alex";

socket.emit('new-user',name);
```

This doesnot work. How do I link the two files without using import/export? Is this even doable in javascript/node?

Note:- I want a steady stream of data flowing from my client.js to my server.js,and my server.js should detect the incoming data with sockets,so import/export is not an option.

Comment: You'd have to use something like redis to be able to do something like this.